# How to display the total length of strings in a string array?

Tags: java, arrays

My code:

```
public class array3 {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] names = {"Einstein", "Newton", "Copernicus", "Kepler"};

        for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
            System.out.println(names[i]);
        }

    }

    }
```

I need to write a code that displays the total length of all the strings in the array I have declared(names). The only thing that comes in my mind for now is to use "names.length" but this will only give the number of elements in the String, not the actual length of the Strings.

Comment: Down vote because I don't like seeing naked guys on S/O.

Comment: Also, your question could of been answered by Google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply put, It can be done by:

```
int s=0; // A variable to store the length
for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++){
    s+=names[i].length(); // add length of each String
}
System.out.println(s); // Print `s`.
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Java 8+, you might use [`Stream.mapToInt(ToIntFunction<? super T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) and [`IntStream.sum()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--) like

```
String[] names = { "Einstein", "Newton", "Copernicus", "Kepler" };
System.out.println(Stream.of(names).mapToInt(String::length).sum());
```

If you want the `length` of *each* `String` you might use a lambda to display the `String` and its' `length` like

```
Stream.of(names).forEach(s -> System.out.printf("%s %d%n", s, s.length()));
```